# How large are header scalar values?

Tags: yellow-paper, block-header

The Yellow paper talks about "scalar values" in section 4.4 to describe block header fields. E.g.

> difficulty: A scalar value corresponding to the dif-
>   ficulty level of this block. This can be calculated
>   from the previous block’s difficulty level and the
>   timestamp; formally Hd.

How large (in bits) are scalar values? Are they fixed size, or variable size?

Answer (score 2):

The header is defined [here](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/d304da380382245190f33878363696cd151201a9/core/types/block.go#L76), and the 5 scalar values are `*big.Int`. These are [arbitrary precision integers](https://golang.org/pkg/math/big/), so variable size.